# Scale Portion of Canvas Android

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, scale, custom-view

I've been searching and searching, trying and trying, but can't seem to figure this out. I have a canvas that has various objects drawn on it (no images/bitmaps). I want to draw another shape on top of it (transparent) and have the elements behind it be scaled - much like a magnify glass. Any thoughts, suggestions, pointers?

Comment: Are all objects on the canvas `Shape`s? Is it alright if the magnified view is pixelated?

Comment: Some is text, some shapes. I suppose pixelated is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new scaled `Bitmap` from the desired portion of the `Bitmap` displayed by the `Canvas` using: [`createBitmap(Bitmap, int, int, int, int, Matrix, boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20boolean%29). Set the `Matrix` to scale to the desired level. Set this new `Bitmap` as the drawable of the magnifying View.

Comment: Thanks. But, I'm not trying to magnify an existing Bitmap, rather various items drawn directly to the canvas (text, roundedRect, circle, etc.). Thoughts?

Comment: The Canvas holds a Bitmap on which all the drawing is done. See the documentation of Canvas. So scale the Bitmap used by the Canvas. Alternatively, you can redraw the Shapes and text under the specified region with a bigger size. This will also avoid pixelation.